# How will USB get devices information

Tags: usb, uwp

how can i in a UWP app get devices information connected via usb port ,at which port also. and how can i check in case of phone. can i also check that device external power source ,means device is charging via adapter or via usb cable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the remarks and code from here [UsbDevice class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.usb.usbdevice.aspx)

See the following code:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched1(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    UInt32 vid = 0x045E;
    UInt32 pid = 0x078F;

    string aqs = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(vid, pid);

    var myDevices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs, null);

    if (myDevices.Count == 0)
    {
        ShowError("Device not found!");
        return;
    }

    UsbDevice device = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);

   // Send a control transfer. 

   UsbSetupPacket initSetupPacket = new UsbSetupPacket() 
   { 
       Request = initRequest,
       RequestType = new UsbControlRequestType() { 

           Recipient = UsbControlRecipient.DefaultInterface,

           ControlTransferType = UsbControlTransferType.Vendor 
       } 
   };

   await device.SendOutControlTransferAsync(initSetupPacket);

}
```

From which you can loop the **deviceinformation** for details. Please check if you can find the info you want.